# C# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql, type-conversion

I have googled for the last few hours and none of those questions can be apply to my case, so hope you guys can help.
I have a report application which user can pick a date from the DateTimePicker and the item which has the largest quantity value would be displayed. I use the report viewer control to display the information.

Here is the SQL query in my table adapter:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
   Drink_Name, 
   SUM(Quantity) AS NoDrink, 
   Bill_No, 
   Staff_No, 
   Bill_Date, 
   Bill_Value, 
   Customer_No, 
   Unit_Price, 
   Quantity
FROM            

   (SELECT        
        Bill.Bill_No,
        Bill.Staff_No, 
        Bill.Bill_Date, 
        Bill.Bill_Value, 
        Bill.Customer_No, 
        Bill_Detail.Drink_Name, 
        Bill_Detail.Bill_No AS Expr1, 
        Bill_Detail.Unit_Price, 
        Bill_Detail.Quantity
    FROM 
        Bill INNER JOIN
         Bill_Detail ON Bill.Bill_No = Bill_Detail.Bill_No
    WHERE        
        (Bill.Bill_Date = @Bill_Date)
   ) AS Temp
   GROUP BY Drink_Name, 
        Bill_No, 
        Staff_No, 
        Bill_Date, 
        Bill_Value, 
        Customer_No, 
        Unit_Price, 
        Quantity
ORDER BY NoDrink DESC
```

And here is the code for generate and load data into report dataset

```
CoffeeShopDataSetTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter adapter = 
    new CoffeeShopDataSetTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter();
CoffeeShopDataSet.DataTable1DataTable table = 
    new CoffeeShopDataSet.DataTable1DataTable();
adapter.FillByMax(table, dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
ReportDataSource maxdatasource = 
    new ReportDataSource("DataSet1form3", (DataTable)table);

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(maxdatasource);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The problem is I always get this error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

When I try the SQL query with the SQL server management 2008, it works just fine, so i think this is the VS problem.
Thanks all in advance.
Sorry for the bad English

Comment: What is the value returned by dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()

Comment: Is `Bill.Bill_Date` a valid datetime field in the database, or is it a character type field (varchar, varchar, etc.)?  Can it contain null values?

Comment: Why are you passing a string instead of a DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

I would be explicit in expressing your Dates so there is no confusion between Date Time formats.

1) Change the line converting the date to string with explicit format

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

2) Change the SQL (Assuming that Bill.Bill_Date column is a Date

```
(Bill.Bill_Date = CONVERT(DATE, @Bill_Date, 112)
```

Comment: I would leave SQL as is and simply pass the actual DateTime value `dateTimePicker1.Value` as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, that would be more ideal, but the CoffeeShopDataSetTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter code is not available so I do not know that data type used as SQLParameter for  @Bill_Date and the FillByMax method parameter will need to change since the second parameter is a string type now.

Comment: @Simon Please try this suggestion and let us know how it works out.